# Can a non-trivial linear combination of three vectors in the three-dimensional space be zero?

Tags: vector-spaces

Apparently it seems to me that a linear combination of three vectors in 3D space (and  as for that, 2 vectors in plane, and one vector in 1D) can never be zero with all their scalars not being zero at once. It always needs an extra vector for each dimension to make their linear combination zero.

Is this true? If true or false, then why?

Comment: Please no caps in title

Comment: I mean, if the vectors are dependent...

Comment: Consider the vectors $i*(1,0,0)$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: This is true if and only if the vectors form a basis for the space (assuming none of the vectors is the zero vector). Do you know what a basis is?

Comment: @MPW A basis cannot contain the zero vector.

Comment: @egreg : Correct. I suppose I could have left that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course it can happen:
$$
3\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}+
2\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 8 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The statement

> *a linear combination of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ is zero if and only if all scalars are zero*

is true if and only if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: And since we are in $\mathbb R^3$, if and only if it forms a basis. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are inventing the definition of dimension. If you have $n$ vectors with two properties

- Everything is a linear combination of those vectors
- The only linear combination that's $0$ has all $0$ coefficients

then you define the dimension of the space to be $n$.

That will be a viable definition once you prove a theorem that says it can't happen for two different values of $n$ for the same space.

You should see a proof in any good linear algebra course or textbook.

Answer (score 1):

In three dimensional space if three vectors are coplanar then one is the linear combination of the other two which makes a linear combination of three vectors being zero without all coefficients being zero.